# Is it possible to use bootcamp for a 2nd installation of Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, boot-camp

I want to have a second installation of Mac OS X which I can tweak without affecting my existing installation. Is it possible to install a 2nd Mac OS X on another partition using Bootcamp, so I have two partitions each with Mac OS X installed?

Secondly, is this safe to do, or is it better to run it in a virtual machine? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to use Bootcamp to do this (Bootcamp allows you to run Windows etc. on your Mac); just partition your drive using Disk Utility and install a second copy of OS X. I've done this on my MacBook Pro without issue (I'm running 10.6 and 10.4). When you start up, hold <kbd>option</kbd> to choose which operating system you wish to boot into (or, to make it even easier so you don't have multiple copies of *Macintosh HD*, use [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/)).

Comment: Volumes can be renamed. Or do they still appear incorrectly as *Macintosh HD* when selecting volumes?

Comment: @Daniel They still appear as *Macintosh HD* in EFI.